# Internet Explorer 11 JavaScript Let Statement

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have rather complex code that is executing a multiple AJAX call in sequence through the 'for' loop. This code works because I use 'Let' statement when assigning scope to a loop index. (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { }.

However, 'Let' is giving me " Expected ';' error in Internet Explorer 11, While the code is working perfectly in other browsers. I have tried to move "let" out of the loop but it still fails, it seem to fail wherever the statement is used regardless of the loop. Please let me know what is the workaround for this as IE 11 is supposed to be compatible with 'Let' statement.

Comment: Are you sure your page isn't running in a compatibility mode?

Comment: IE11 knows `let` but it works like `var`.

Comment: Read note 5 here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=let

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this ES6 support table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). Internet Explorer 11 does not support `let` in *for/for-in loop iteration scope*.

You need to take a different approach.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/19068) lists a number of options you could implement manually.

You could also use a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 or newer JavaScript into ES5.

Comment: `let` is partially supported on IE 11; where it doesn't have block level scope.

Comment: @AdeshM — So? I never claimed otherwise (I was very specific in the first paragraph of this answer), and the whole point of the use in the question is that it is block scope.

Comment: if you use `let` in a for loop constructor in IE11, what happens? Does it just get converted to var, or does it actually break?